# A median of a triangle is the geometric mean of the adjacent sides; find the cosine of one angle in terms of the others

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, absolute-value

> $AD$ is a median of $\triangle ABC$. $|AD|$ is the geometric mean of $|AB|$ and  $|AC|$.
>
> Find $1+\cos A$ in terms of $\cos B$ and $\cos C$.

Edit

This is the second part of the question

Also prove that 1+cosA=√2|cosB-cosC|.

Comment: I have rolled back this question to the form in which the answers were given. It is not a good practice to change your question after you have received answers. This presents a moving target and is unkind and unfair to those who help you. In the future, if you are looking for an answer of a particular form or using a specific technique, then include that in your question. You may find it necessary to ask another question in which you are specific. If you do so, then you should be very clear about what help you've received so far, what you've tried since receiving it, and what you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}=\sqrt{bc},$$ which gives
$$a^2=2b^2+2c^2-4bc.$$
Thus, $b\neq c$ and 
$$\cos\beta\cos\gamma=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=$$
$$=\frac{(2b^2+2c^2-4bc+c^2-b^2)(2b^2+2c^2-4bc+b^2-c^2)}{4(2b^2+2c^2-4bc)bc}=$$
$$=\frac{(3c^2-4bc+b^2)(3b^2-4bc+c^2)}{8(b-c)^2bc}=\frac{(b-c)^2(3b-c)(b-3c)}{8bc(b-c)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{3(b^2+c^2)-10bc}{8bc}=\frac{3}{8}\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\right)-\frac{5}{4}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}=\frac{10+8\cos\beta\cos\gamma}{3}.$$
Id est, $$1+\cos\alpha=1+\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=1+\frac{b^2+c^2-2b^2-2c^2+4bc}{2bc}=$$
$$=3-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{b}\right)=3-\frac{5+4\cos\beta\cos\gamma}{3}=\frac{4}{3}(1-\cos\beta\cos\gamma).$$

About your second problem.
$$1+\cos\alpha=1+\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=$$
$$=1+\frac{b^2+c^2-2b^2-2c^2+4bc}{2bc}=3-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right).$$
Also, we see that $3-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)\geq0$.

In another hand,
$$\sqrt2|\cos\beta-\cos\gamma|=\sqrt2\left|\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}-\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right|=$$
$$=\sqrt2\left|\frac{2b^2+2c^2-4bc+c^2-b^2}{2ac}-\frac{2b^2+2c^2-4bc+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\right|=$$
$$=\sqrt2\left|\frac{b^2-4bc+3c^2}{2ac}-\frac{3b^2-4bc+c^2}{2ab}\right|=$$
$$=\sqrt2|b-c|\cdot\left|\frac{b-3c}{2ac}-\frac{3b-c}{2ab}\right|=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt2|b-c|}{2abc}\cdot\left|(b-3c)b-(3b-c)c\right|=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt2|b-c|}{2\sqrt2|b-c|bc}\cdot\left|b^2+c^2-6bc\right|=$$
$$=3-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\right)$$ and we are done!

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to the updated form

Comment: @user481779 I think It's another problem. I think it's not fair to change the problem. The previous problem was solved. Accept please this problem and I'll think about your new. Thank you.

Comment: What you have done is absolutely correct. I am just asking you if you can modify your answer

Comment: @user481779 Accept before my solution (use V) and I'll post a solution for your new problem.

Comment: @Jean Marie He accepted and when I posted the second solution he removed this accept.

Comment: I just want to have a look at different methods. I would definitely accept your answer after sometime

Comment: @Jean Marie So post it. It's OK.

Comment: @user481779 You cannot say that you were waiting other answers because you have radically changed your question. Michael had answered in a correct way, spending time on his writing You had thus validate his answer and ask a new question.

Comment: @user481779: *"I would definitely accept your answer after sometime."* So, not only did you disingenuously accept Michael's answer in order to coax him into providing additional work on your behalf, you now encourage others to do *even more* work, despite planning to deny them the rewards of accepting that work. Granted, we're talking about silly internet points here, but still: that behavior is disappointing. As you spend more time here, I hope that you will become much more considerate and appreciative of the time and effort that you are asking people to invest in your education.

Comment: I'm sorry if that didn't go well with you.This was not my purpose. I didn't accept your answer at first but you asked me to accept it .Nevertheless I feel it was wrong on my part to do that.Thank you for still not removing your answer.Also I have accepted your answer

Comment: @JeanMarie I request you to post your answer as it would help others.Nobody else must miss on different things due to my mistake.

Comment: Should I upload the second part of the question as a separate question?

Comment: @user481779 I don't remember your "2nd part" and in particular I don't remember the degree of gap between the first and the second part. Could you recall it ? If it is in the same vein, you could add an **Edit** followed by an explicit explanation that it is asked now and wasn't in the primitive version. If it sufficiently different, the best is to ask a new question with explicit reference to the first one.

Answer (score 2):

From these easily-proven relations (for any $\triangle ABC$) ...

$$\begin{align}
b &= a \cos C + c \cos A \\
c &= a \cos B + b \cos A
\end{align}\tag{1}$$

... we deduce ...
$$(b - c)(1+\cos A) = a(\cos C - \cos B) \tag{2}$$

For a triangle whose median from $A$ has a length, $d$, equal to the geometric mean of $b$ and $c$ (that is, $d^2 = b c$), [Stewart's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem) (for instance) yields ...
$$b^2\cdot \frac{a}{2} + c^2\cdot\frac{a}{2} = a\left(d^2 + \frac{a}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{2}\right)\quad\to\quad a^2 = 2 (b-c)^2 \tag{3}$$

Therefore, incorporating $(2)$, we can write (since $b \neq c$, and $1+\cos A > 0$ (why?)) ...
$$(1 + \cos A)^2 = 2\;(\cos C - \cos B)^2 \quad\to\quad 1 + \cos A = \sqrt{2}\;|\cos B - \cos C| \tag{4}$$
... as desired. $\square$

---

**Note.** I'm posting this answer because I think it's worth sharing. I do not condone OP's ploy of accepting @Michael's answer in order to get more effort from him, and then subsequently un-accepting it in order to get more effort from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the new, more relaxed context, here is a proof by analytic geometry.

It connects the issue with conic curves, simplifying the problem by using a single variable as we are going to see it (see figure at the bottom).

WLOG, one can assume that $B(-1,0), C(1,0)$ are fixed (thus their midpoint is $D=O$), and $A$ is variable with coordinates $(x,y)$.

The geometric mean condition, written under the form:

$$(AB.AC)^2=AO^4$$ is equivalent to

$$[(x+1)^2+y^2][(x-1)^2+y^2]=(x^2+y^2)^2$$

itself equivalent to

$$\tag{1}x^2-y^2=\tfrac12,$$

meaning that point $A$ must belong to a certain hyperbola $(H)$.

Let us assume, again WLOG, that point $A$ is on the right branch of the hyperbola (i.e., with $x>\tfrac12$).

Then using relationship $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(A)$ and the two others by cyclic permutation, replacing $y^2$ by $x^2-\dfrac12$ (see (1)), one obtains

$$\cos(A)=\dfrac{4x^2-3}{4x^2-1}, \ \ \cos(B)=\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1+x}{2x+1}, \ \ \cos(C)=\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1-x}{2x-1}.$$

yielding the final relationship:

$\sqrt{2}(\cos(B)-\cos(C)) = (\sqrt{2})^2\dfrac{2-4x^2}{1-4x^2}=\dfrac{4-8x^2}{1-4x^2}=1+\dfrac{3-4x^2}{1-4x^2}=1+\cos(A)$

(no need for absolute values because of the choice $x>0$ for the abscissa of $A$).

**Remark :**

It can be easily proven that hyperbola $(H)$ has $B$ and $C$ as its foci! Moreover $(H)$ can be described as the locus of points $A$ such that

$$|AB-AC|=constant=(1+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=\dfrac12.$$

[image]

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Taking into account the fact that the OP has completely changed his attitude, I have finally given my proof in an extended way.